# In R, how can I print the name of an object reliably from a custom print function?

Tags: r, printing, console

I created a class in R, and am trying to create a print function for that class.  I'd like the print function to print the name of the object being passed to the print function.  Using the standard `deparse(substitute())` I can get the name of the variable, and this works when I call the `print()` function directly.  But it doesn't work when I just run the variable from R Studio.  It is obviously calling my print function.  But there is some indirection that is causing it to lose the variable name.  Here is an example:

```
# Define class 'myobj'
myobj <- function(val) {
  
  obj <- structure(list(), class = c("myobj", "list")) 
  
  obj$value = val
  
  return(obj)
}

# Write custom print function for 'myobj' class
#' @export
print.myobj <- function(x, ...) {
  
  nm <- deparse1(substitute(x, env = environment()))
  cat(paste0("My object name: ", nm, "\n"))
  cat(paste0("My object value: ", x$value, "\n"))
      
  invisible(x)
}

myInstance <- myobj(123)

# Prints name and value.  
print(myInstance)

#> My object name: myInstance
#> My object value: 123

# Prints value, but name is local variable 'x'. 
myInstance

#> My object name: x
#> My object value: 123
```

It seems like when you run the variable directly, it is getting nested in another frame or environment, such that the `deparse(substitute())` isn't working.

How can I get my print function to print the name of the variable reliably, no matter how it is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The autoprinting [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Autoprinting) says it is handled by `print.c`.

This function looks like this.

```cpp
static void PrintObjectS3(SEXP s, R_PrintData *data)
{
    /*
      Bind value to a variable in a local environment, similar to
      a local({ x <- <value>; print(x) }) call. This avoids
      problems in previous approaches with value duplication and
      evaluating the value, which might be a call object.
    */
    SEXP xsym = install("x");
    SEXP mask = PROTECT(NewEnvironment(R_NilValue, R_NilValue, data->env));
    defineVar(xsym, s, mask);

    /* Forward user-supplied arguments to print() */
    SEXP fun = PROTECT(findFun(install("print"), R_BaseNamespace));
    SEXP args = PROTECT(cons(xsym, data->callArgs));
    SEXP call = PROTECT(lcons(fun, args));

    eval(call, mask);

    defineVar(xsym, R_NilValue, mask); /* To eliminate reference to s */
    UNPROTECT(4); /* mask, fun, args, call */
}
```

Note that it says

> similar to a `local({ x <- <value>; print(x) })`

So autoprinting does not directly call `print(myInstance)`. It does things with the symbol `x` so I think getting the variable name in the way you want is not possible.

The difference can be seen by looking at the `traceback`.

```
print.myobj <- function(x, ...) {
  stop()
}

print(myInstance)
#> (Traceback)
#> 3. stop() 
#> 2. print.myobj(myInstance) 
#> 1. print(myInstance) 

myInstance
#> (Traceback)
#> 3. stop() 
#> 2. print.myobj(x) 
#> 1. (function (x, ...) 
#>    UseMethod("print"))(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer.  First, I didn't realize the source of the 'x'. You are right, it is not my local 'x'.  It is the 'x' from PrintObjectS3.  When I change the local variable to something else, I still get an 'x'.

Comment: But I'm still wondering if I can jigger the dispatch somehow to make it work.  Do you think it is possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.